# Junit testing and debugging

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am trying to run a few junit tests and I come across this error in several tests.
These are the errors I am getting.

```
[junit] Could not get property value
    [junit] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not get property value
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.getMemberValue(ClassValidator.java:539)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.getInvalidValues(ClassValidator.java:384)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.getInvalidValues(ClassValidator.java:352)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.validator.event.ValidateEventListener.validate(ValidateEventListener.java:139)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.validator.event.ValidateEventListener.onPreInsert(ValidateEventListener.java:172)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:177)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:72)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:260)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:179)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.flushIfNecessary(HibernateAccessor.java:390)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:408)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:375)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:738)
    [junit]     at org.unavco.pbo.mdm.dao.hibernate.BaseDaoHibernate.saveObject(BaseDaoHibernate.java:52)
    [junit]     at org.unavco.pbo.mdm.dao.hibernate.StationDaoHibernate.saveStation(StationDaoHibernate.java:201)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    [junit]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.saveStation(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.unavco.pbo.mdm.dao.StationFourcharBackwardCompatTest.createAndSaveStation(StationFourcharBackwardCompatTest.java:228)
    [junit]     at org.unavco.pbo.mdm.dao.StationFourcharBackwardCompatTest.testStationWithFourcharInherit(StationFourcharBackwardCompatTest.java:49)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:79)
    [junit] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to invoke validateProjectDate
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXMethod.invoke(JavaXMethod.java:66)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.getMemberValue(ClassValidator.java:536)
    [junit] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXMethod.invoke(JavaXMethod.java:57)
    [junit] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    [junit]     at org.unavco.pbo.mdm.model.Station.validateProjectDate(Station.java:740)
```

Code the last line it is refering to.

```
@AssertTrue
    private boolean validateProjectDate() {
        if (projectDate.before(this.stationProject.getStartDate()))  {
            return false;
        }

        if (projectDate.after(this.stationProject.getEndDate())) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The test that is affected.

public void testStationWithFourcharInherit() throws Exception {

```
String fourCharId = "IOA2";
Date projectDate = new Date();

endTransaction();
Locale locale = createAndSaveLocale(fourCharId);
Site site = createAndSaveSite(locale);
Station station = createAndSaveStation(site, fourCharId);
startNewTransaction();

verifyStationMatches(station, fourCharId);
```

}

The refered function in test.

```
protected Station createAndSaveStation(Site site, String fourCharId) {
        Station station = new Station();
        station.setLongName("MyStationsLongName");
        if (fourCharId != null) {
            station.setFourCharId(fourCharId);
        }
        StationType stnType = (StationType) stationDao.getObject(StationType.class, 1L);
        station.setStationType(stnType);
        StationBuildStatus bldStat = (StationBuildStatus) stationDao.getObject(StationBuildStatus.class, 1L);
        station.setStationBuildStatus(bldStat);
        Project stnProject = (Project) stationDao.getObject(Project.class, 1L);
        station.setStationProject(stnProject);
        station.setCommsType(CommsType.CDMA);
        station.setLatitude(31.009);
        station.setLongitude(128.9930);
        station.setElevation(890.3);
        station.setStationStatus(StationOperationalStatus.Operable);
        station.setLongName("long name");
        station.setInstallDate(new Date());
        station.setProjectDate(new Date());
        site.addStation(station);
        stationDao.saveStation(station);
        stationDao.validateStartDate(station);
        return station;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException [junit] at org.unavco.pbo.mdm.model.Station.validateProjectDate(Station.java:740) ?

Comment: Code: 
 @AssertTrue
 private boolean validateProjectDate() {
  if (projectDate.before(this.stationProject.getStartDate()))  {
   return false;
  }

  if (projectDate.after(this.stationProject.getEndDate())) {
   return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

Comment: Your test does not set this code up correctly. Find out why.

Comment: Do I need an assertTrue in the test?

Comment: First find out where you get the nullpointerexception which I would guess is stationProject not set properly, and then figure out how to have it set properly.  You usually need to do this manually in test scaffolding

Comment: This is how i call in stationProject                                                                                                                                                                    /**
  * [at}return
  * {at}hibernate.many-to-one column="idproject" not-null="false"
  * class="org.unavco.pbo.mdm.model.Project"
  * cascade="save-update"
  */
 {at}Required
 public Project getStationProject() {
  return stationProject;
 }

 public void setStationProject(Project stationProject) {
  this.stationProject = stationProject;
 }

Comment: You think you do.  Try setting breakpoints and see what actually happens.

Comment: Is this.stationProject always null? Update: Nevermind its not null and gets filled in. I can see the value pull up on the UI.

Comment: THen something else is broken. You remembered to find out what actually caused the nullpointerexception?

Comment: I think that its my validateStartDate function. I  also realized that I do not have a way to catch a null value, if my project does not have an enddate it does nothing.

Comment: This is the code I have right now.  @AssertTrue
 private boolean validateProjectDate() {
//  boolean date ;
  if (projectDate.before(this.stationProject.getStartDate()))  {
//   date = false
   return false;
  }

  if (projectDate.after(this.stationProject.getEndDate())) {
//   date = false;
   return false;
  }

  if (this.stationProject.getEndDate() == null){
   throw new NullPointerException();
  }

  return true;
//  return date;
 }

Comment: Find out what causes your exception and figure out how to avoid that.

Comment: I went back and made my tests run when I commented out this  @AssertTrue
 private boolean validateProjectDate() {

  if (projectDate.before(this.stationProject.getStartDate()))  {

   return false;
  }

  if (projectDate.after(this.stationProject.getEndDate())) {

   return false;
  }

  if (this.stationProject.getEndDate() == null){
//   throw new NullPointerException();
   return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

Comment: And when I uncomment it I get the error --> [junit] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    [junit]  at java.util.Date.getMillisOf(Date.java:958)
    [junit]  at java.util.Date.after(Date.java:931)
    [junit]  at org.unavco.pbo.mdm.model.Station.validateProjectDate(Station.java:753)
    [junit] 
 I need the validation for my database constraints that save correct data from the UI.

Comment: Update: I added the line                                                                                             
 if (this.stationProject.getEndDate() == null){
   return false;
  }. before everything else in this block of code. Now i get the following errror, [junit] Testcase: testStationSiteChange(org.unavco.pbo.mdm.dao.StationFourcharBackwardCompatTest): Caused an ERROR
    [junit] validation failed for: org.unavco.pbo.mdm.model.Station
    [junit] org.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException: validation failed for: org.unavco.pbo.mdm.model.Station

Comment: I am now having another error pop up that I am not sure what this means.   '''rg.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException: validation failed for: org.unavco.pbo.mdm.model.Station'''

Comment: I suggest you practice testing on something simpler.